# ngx graph - Store the state of the graph after repositioning some nodes

Tags: angular, graph, ngx-charts, ngx-graph

The ngx-graph is used to draw flow diagram in angular.
The algorithm automatically aligns the nodes with proper spacing.
Also there is a feature to drag the nodes from their initial positions
But on page refresh all the changes made by the user are lost as the algorithm rebuilds the graph.

Is it possible to save the state of the graph after the user repositions them?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. It begs the question, 'why can the user drag the nodes?' ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no, from the library, you won't get this ability but if you maintain your layout file you can select to calculate the layout or use existing points.
Which points to use? the set of points that you already calculate on the first load and saved it on your app.
So it requires some work but possible, it's not a feature that is part of the graph but needs to be maintain on the layout level.

Hope I was clear.

Comment: the layout mainintaing is not very possible in the ngx-graph as far as I ve seen. you have any suggestions?

Comment: It requires some work and understanding for layout modifications. You can use the default layout.